# My user credentials into a visualforce email

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, user

Hello I have created a Visualforce email for my division. I would like my user credentials to appear at the end of the email. If you look the attached file of an example from normal email in gmail. 
I do have the details saved into Setup->Manage Users->Users->........
How can I get those details into the VF email that I have created

Example image[image: email with details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualforce has some [Global Variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm) available including a [$User](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_user.htm) one. So you can use e.g.:

```
{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}
```

in your Visualforce template.

Comment: When I use the $User, I get errors like Error: Field Company does not exist. Check spelling

Comment: @TommyGeorgiou You are definitely choosing to use a Visualforce email template not one of the other types? And adding something like `{!$User.FirstName}`?

Comment: Yes its VF email template. I do get the name and last name but $User.Company & $User.Address are not displaying

Comment: Sorry for the hustle. I managed to get the address by having $User.Street $User.City etc but still won't let me with the $User.Company

Comment: My bad!! Had to use $User.CompanyName